# Gatling check does not fail

Tags: gatling

I am trying to send a http request and fail if the request returns not 200:

```
exec(http("Get some html")
      .get("${aggUrl}/somePath")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(regex("websocket=(.*?)&").saveAs("wsLink"))
)
```

The server sends the 401 response:

```
[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]{"errors":[{"code":"authentication.failure","message":"Failed to authenticate user details"}]}]
```

I expect in console something like "expecting code 200, but was 401"

But the actual error is:

```
[ERROR] i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-38' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'wsLink' is defined', forwarding to the next one
[ERROR] i.g.h.a.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-37' failed to execute: No attribute named 'wsLink' is defined
```

So I assume that the ".check(status.is(200))" is just ignored?

How then should I fail the test?

Thanks in advance,
Andrei Isakov

Comment: Which version of Gatling do you use? Have you upgraded to the latest version (3.4.0 as of now)?

Comment: Hello Stephane! Yes, I use gatling 3.4.0:

        <gatling.version>3.4.0</gatling.version>
        <gatling.plugin.version>3.1.0</gatling.plugin.version>
        <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.4.0</scala-maven-plugin.version>

The same behavior was in gatling 3.3.1.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I see the output of regex check, but do not see the output of the status check.

There is a field "displayActualValue" in this check, but I have no idea how to use it. The compiler always complain. Is there an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken.

```
[ERROR] i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-38' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'wsLink' is defined', forwarding to the next one
[ERROR] i.g.h.a.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-37' failed to execute: No attribute named 'wsLink' is defined
```

Those errors happens happen **AFTER** the request you provided the code for, in an `exec` block you didn't mentioned where you're trying to inspect the Session's content and fetch the `wsLink` attribute that doesn't exist because the request failed.

Check failures are not logged with ERROR level. You have to either lower the logging level (see `logback.xml`) or check the HTML reports.